# Not-adaptive icons on Android 8

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, adaptive-icon

I'm working on an app that gets a really ugly icon on Android 8 (like the LinkedIn app in the image below). To solve this issue, the Internet says that I need to implement adaptive icons. Fair enough. The problem is that the company that owns the app wants a square icon, but that is not guaranteed with adaptive icons. I see that some apps have square, non-ugly icons on Android 8 (such as Morning Routine and Norsk Tipping in the image). Anyone knows how this is done?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: prolly as simple as it is possible: by defining icon only(and not roundIcon) which is square png putted into mipmap-xxx

Comment: Thank you for answering, @Selvin! Yes, my manifest contains this:

`android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

and refs to a square image, but android puts the square image inside a white circle.. :P

Comment: "the company that owns the app wants a square icon, but that is not guaranteed with adaptive icons" -- it is not guaranteed anywhere. Home screen developers can do what they want, and some home screen developers have been applying their own masks, backgrounds, and whatnot to launcher icons. Google is merely standardizing the practice, so developers are likely to get more consistent results, if not necessarily complete control over those results.

Comment: I see... But do you know why my square icon is forced into a white bouble whilst other icons keep their square shape? @CommonsWare

Comment: That is covered in the duplicate: their `targetSdkVersion` is below 26. Once their `targetSdkVersion` rises to 26 or higher, they too will be affected. And [the upcoming Android version ratchet](https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/01/08/android-version-ratchet.html) means that you cannot keep an artificially low `targetSdkVersion` indefinitely, if you wish to ship on the Play Store.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @CommonsWare! Have a nice weekend!